# Why isn't my conditional doing anything?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

I'm making a simple tic-tac-toe game but for some reason when trying to create the rules for the game, I can't seem to get anything to work. I have a multidimensional array that has the rules in it but I can't even get one cell to react accordingly. What's wrong with the bottom if statement in my JavaScript pannel?
http://jsfiddle.net/Cp4Lu/1/
(This is the if statement I'm referring to)

```
if (c9.text === 'X') {
alert("You win!");
}
```

Comment: that isn't in any events, so it happens exactly once.

Comment: @DanielA.White so what could I do to fix that?

Comment: `id`s should not begin with a digit?

Comment: @Teemu What are you referring to?

Comment: In you fiddle there are these: `<td id='1'></td>`

Comment: there's lot of work remaining, You are not even storing where both players have checked and as mentioned there are couple of problems with your code too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple problems

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: c9 is not defined
```

- You're using `c9` outside of the scope in which it is defined
- The `if (c9...` isn't inside any [event listener](http://api.jquery.com/on/), so it only happens the first time when the *JavaScript* runs initially
- jQuery's [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) is a *function*, not a property
- an *id* in *HTML* [should begin with a letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Comment: Does that mean I'll have to define my winConditions either in or before my event listener where I define my table cell variables?

Comment: If you want to use the variables in your `document.ready` _function_, you need to have the code that uses them either in the same/child scope, or you need to `var` them differently.

Comment: How would I 'var' them differently?

Comment: write the `var` in a common ancestor scope, then set them in the `document.ready` _function_ without a second `var`.

Comment: If you make that change and start getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'foobar' of undefined`, then the variable has been `var`d, but not set yet (i.e. you're trying to use it before it's ready)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/Cp4Lu/4/

I basically put all your code in the $(document).ready and put your conditional within your click event. I believe it now does what you were looking for.

```
$('td').on('click', function () {
    turnCount += 1;
    setCurrentPlayer();
    $(this).text(currentPlayer);
    console.log(turnCount);
    if (c9.text() === 'X') {
        alert("You win!");
    }
});
```